# Equalizing sizes of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, size, equality

Say we have the following two matrices in `matlab`:

`>> x=[1 5;7 8;9 6]`

`>> y=[6 87]`

I'm trying to make them have the same size. I did that by making the size of `y` to be the same as the size of `x`. But, when I call `y` again, I get the result as the original dimension.

I want them to have the same dimensions since for instance if I want to measure the distance between them they have to have the same dimensions.

So, the other cells can have `zero` values for instance.

How can I make that in matlab?

Thanks.

Comment: Want to do zero padding ?

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau. Do you mean using `zeros`? In this case, how can I leave the original values of `y`?

Comment: No, I mean. What you really want ? Your question isn`t clear. Because by doing `y = size(x)`, y will be fill with the size of the matrix x ([3,2] right now). You want to have same size matrix for multiplaction ? Specify more informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
y = padarray(y,size(x)-size(y),'post');
```

Be sure that size(x) > size(y).

For more information have a look to : [padarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html)